# select element by driver.find_element_by_xpath used by selenium for span class

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape data and click ot from a page using xpath . For example, the content I want is in the following format

```
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;" unselectable="on">
<img class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-empty" role="presentation" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
<img class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-line" role="presentation" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
<img class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow" role="presentation" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
<img class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf " role="presentation" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==">
<span class="x-tree-node-text ">Chassis</span>
```

I have used the function //span[contains(@class, 'x-tree-node-text')].Chassis  but its is not returning anything.

Any Help?

Comment: why you need contains , use xpath checker to verify your result without running your code (better to use css selector)

Comment: `not returning anything` Do you mean that you get `NoSuchElement` exception or what?

Comment: Yes i am not finding the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to find the text "Chassis" as well? It's hard to see bc you haven't put your XPath in backticks.

But if so, then your XPath is wrong. You have to use:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'x-tree-node-text')][.='Chassis']
```

Comment: I used this as:

    xpath="//span[contains(@class, 'x-tree-node-text')][.='Chassis']"
    xpath.click()

It throws error as:  
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: You cannot click a string. You need to feed the xpath string into `driver.findElement()` in order to get the web element. Then you can call `element.click()`. Full code:  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'x-tree-node-text')][.='Chassis']")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath:-

```
//span[@class='x-tree-node-text ']
```

OR more specific

```
//span[@class='x-tree-node-text ' and contains(.,'Chassis')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have multiple class with the name "class='x-tree-node-text' " so value inside span differentiate them.  
    <span class="x-tree-node-text ">Chassis</span>
    <span class="x-tree-node-text ">Config</span>